# return when duplicate html table

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a function that can remove the duplicate in my html table.

```js
var seen = {};
$('#tblSerial tr').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();
  txt = txt.trim();

  if (seen[txt]) {
    isExist = true;
    alertify.error("This serial is already on contract.");
    $(this).remove();

    return; //this should return
    
  } else
    seen[txt] = true;
});
```

But the problem now is that, below that code there's an AJAX call which always call even I **return** in the duplicate error.

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: siteURL + '@Url.Action("valcontract", "contract")',
                data: data_model,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.success) { 

                    } else {
                        $('#serial').val("");

                        alertify
                        .error(response.responseText);

                        return;
                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alertify
                    .error(response.responseText);

                    return;
                }
        });
```

I want to block the AJAX call if there's a duplicate in my serial table.

Comment: You can add a boolean `duplicate = false;` and then `if (seen[txt]) { duplicate = true;` and just before the ajax `if(!duplicate){ //Ajax call`

Comment: Once you've started the AJAX operation, it can't be stopped. What you can do is to validate first if you have duplicates on your serial table before starting the AJAX operation